# Looking for a way to represent data in a text file as a graph

Tags: perl, command-line, vbscript, batch-file

I have a text file that i would like to output as a graph. The text file looks something like this -

```
Item 1
---
        1234
Item2
---
      5678
Item3
----
      910112
```

I would like to output it to a bar graph or a pie chart. What would the best way to do this be?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use GD::Graph

```
use strict;
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::hbars;
use GD::Graph::Data;

#For some reason, installing GD::Graph didn't put save.pl in my @INC path
require "/usr/share/doc/libgd-graph-perl/examples/samples/save.pl";

my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([
    ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"],
    [1234, 5678, 910112],
    ]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;

my @names = qw/GDbars123 GDbars123-h/;

for my $my_graph (GD::Graph::bars->new, GD::Graph::hbars->new)
{
    my $name = shift @names;

    print STDERR "Processing $name\n";

    $my_graph->set( 
    x_label         => 'X Label',
    y_label         => 'Y label',
    title           => 'A Simple Bar Chart',
    #y_max_value     => 8,
    #y_tick_number   => 8,
    #y_label_skip    => 2,

    #x_labels_vertical => 1,

    # shadows
    bar_spacing     => 8,
    shadow_depth    => 4,
    shadowclr       => 'dred',

    transparent     => 0,
    ) 
    or warn $my_graph->error;

    $my_graph->plot($data) or die $my_graph->error;
    save_chart($my_graph, $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actual image, use [Chart::Pie](http://search.cpan.org/~karlon/Chart-Pie-0.90/Pie.pod#EXAMPLE_1_-_Simple_Pie_Chart) (IIRC it maks GIFs) - the link is an example of usage in POD.

The same [Chart package](http://search.cpan.org/~chartgrp/Chart/) also has [Chart::Bars](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Chart/Chart.pod) as well